# How does the Unchained's talent, 'Dissipate' stack with the Block Cost Reduction property?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide-2

The Unchained's level 20 talent, *Dissipate* is described in-game as:

> Block cost is reduced by 50% when Overcharged and blocking attacks vent Overcharge.

How does this stack with the 'Block Cost Reduction' property in melee weapons and necklaces? e.g., If I already have 30% Block Cost Reduction from a necklace, how will this stack with *Dissipate*? What will my total block cost reduction be?